# android studio add library project error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-studio, library-project

I tried to add ActionBarSherlock library to my HelloWorld project.
I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/2407522) strictly but i had this 2 errors :

> Gradle:  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':libraries:actionbarsherlock:compileRelease'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Second :

> Could not execute build using Gradle distribution
>   'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.

trace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':librari es:actionbarsherlock:compileRelease'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex ecute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExec uter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockReleasingTaskE xecuter$1.run(CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(Def aultCacheAccess.java:179)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(Def aultCacheAccess.java:232)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunning Operation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStat eCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockReleasingTaskE xecuter.execute(CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.exec ute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ContextualisingTaskExecuter.e xecute(ContextualisingTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskE xecuter$1.run(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAcc ess.java:124)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAcc ess.java:112)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(De faultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStat eCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskE xecuter.execute(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execut e(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecu ter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter .execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execut e(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter .execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailur e(AbstractTask.java:282)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(De faultTaskPlanExecutor.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(De faultTaskPlanExecutor.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(Defaul tTaskPlanExecutor.java:27)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(Defau ltTaskGraphExecuter.java:89)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTask ExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute r.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExec uter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecu ter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBu ildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAcc ess.java:124)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAcc ess.java:112)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(De faultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStat eCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBu ildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute r.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExec uter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecu ter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildEx ecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute r.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecute r.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default GradleLauncher.java:166)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle Launcher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun cher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon troller.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav a:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav a:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce ssBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce ssBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions .java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction. execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction. execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute( CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute( CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep ortingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep ortingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBoots trap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.j ava:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.ja va:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48) Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Com pilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(J dk6JavaCompiler.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(J dk6JavaCompiler.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegat eAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute (NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute (NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute( DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute( DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:20)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport. execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport. execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:24)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.Compile.compile(Compile.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMeth od(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObj ect.java:122)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(Composite DynamicObject.java:147)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unkno wn Source)
        at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF actory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:217)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF actory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskF actory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:199)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(Abstra ctTask.java:526)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(Abstra ctTask.java:509)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex ecuteAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 70 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.576 secs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after days of trying i solved it !
In the previous referenced answer in step 8 :

> Now in Actionbarsherlock module delete android-support-library (because this is second copy of this library - it will cause build errors).

Just i ignored this step and it works fine for me.